# Rails ActiveRecord to_json leaving invalid json characters

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json

I am trying to convert a rails ActiveRecord to json and keep getting invalid characters when I try to parse the data.

```
@appts = current_cbu.appointments.on_date(@date).as_json.to_json
```

I have overridden the 'as_json method as follows:

```
  def as_json
    hash = {}
    hash["title"] = calendar_title
    hash["start"] = start_at.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    hash["end"] = end_at.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    hash["url"] = "/admin/appointments/#{id}"
    hash["base_amount"] = base_amount
    hash["upcharge_amount"] = upcharge_amount
    hash["upcharge_reason"] = upcharge_reason
    hash["total_with_tip_amount"] = total_with_tip_amount
    hash["customer_notes"] = customer_notes
    hash
  end
```

Then in my view I post this to a separate application, but on the separate application i get errors when I try to do JSON.parse(). How can I convert @appts to valid json without having to do a .gsub for every character that is invalid?

```
 var post_data = {
    'type': 'initial',
    'appts': '#{@appts}',
    'assignments': '#{@daily_assignments_json}',
    'events': '#{@events_json}',
    'date' : '#{@date}'
  }
  targetWindow.postMessage(JSON.stringify(post_data), '#{@scheduler_location}');
```

Error: VM30212:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 
 in JSON at position 663

Comment: What is the exact error you're getting? What specifically does `@appts` look like server-side? What specifically does the JSON look like client-side? That JavaScript at the bottom of your question looks like it is trying to mix Ruby string interpolation with JavaScript, what's going there?

Comment: edited post to include @muistooshort

Comment: Something doesn't add up. There's a `notes` key client-side but nothing server-side produces that. Where is that `as_json` override? And how are you getting the data from the server to the client?

Comment: @muistooshort Sorry, that was also in the as_json function, in the original post, i just removed a lot of fields to make it easier to follow

Comment: But how is the data getting from the server to the client? Are you just throwing an unencoded string into some JavaScript?

Comment: yes @muistooshort

Comment: Post what is generated in your HTML by `JSON.stringify(post_data)`.